# Convert only specific tags using ng-bind-html

Tags: html, angularjs, laravel, tinymce, ng-bind-html

I am using the text editor `TinyMCE` and I am trying to differentiate `code` from the general description when retrieving the data from the database . It is meant to be like the StackOverflows editor. However, I can convert **all** the `html` tags by using ng-bind-html which is the main problem. I don't want to convert the `code` part.
For example:

```
<strong>hello</strong>
<code>
     <div>i dont want the tags inside code to be converted</div>
     <p>i am para</p>
</code>
```

The desired output is:

**hello**

```
<code>
     <div>i dont want the tags inside code to be converted</div>
     <p>i am para</p>
</code>
```

However, the output I am getting by using ng-bind-html is:

"
**hello**

i dont want the tags inside code to be converted

i am para."

I am using `angular 1.52` and `laravel php`.

My partial:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myResult">

</div>
```

Backend controller:

```
public function getquesdet(){
    $id = Request::input('id');

    $data= Data::where('id','=',$id)->first();
    $body = html_entity_decode($data['body']);

    return html_entity_decode($body);

}
```

My angularjs controller:

```
app.controller('seperatequestion',['$scope','$rootScope','$http','$stateParams',function($scope,$rootScope,$http,$stateParams){
$http({
    method:'GET',
    url : $rootScope.apiend + '/getquestiondet',
    params:{
        id:$stateParams.qid
    }
}).success(function(result){
    $scope.myResult= result;

}).error(function(data){
    console.log(data);
})

}])
```

So, all I want is to convert the html tags excluding the tags inside the `code` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE already has a plugin to address what you are trying to do:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/codesample/

Note that when you render the content outside of TinyMCE you will need to include Prism (http://prismjs.com/index.html) in your rendered page to get the same look.