# Reach only a specific html tag as an object value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, api, object

I'm working on Angular js (1.6) and for the first time I have to deal with an API which contain several objects like this:

```
{
  "description": " <p><a href=\"url">link</a>text</p><p><a href=\"other 
  url"><img src=\"another url" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"text\" />
  </a></p> <p>text</p>"
}
```

I found a way how to display the entire value with "ng-bind-html" but for some place in the webapp I only need the a tag or the img tag or the p tag.

My question is: Is it possible to display dynamically only a specific html tag of an object value like above?

Thank you for your time and your answers.

Comment: what about filtering specific tag and then bind?

Comment: Hum sorry it's quite vague can you develop please or share a documentation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063895/convert-only-specific-tags-using-ng-bind-html

Comment: Well thank you for this discovery but it look too heavy to implement and it removes html tags. I think that I need to keep and target the markups because if I transform my html into a long string how will I bind dynamically just a link or a text? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a string. So, as any string, you can do this.

```
var str = "<p><a href=\'url'>link</a>text</p><p><a href=\'otherurl'><img src=\'another url' width=\'240\' height=\'160\' alt=\'text\' /></a></p> <p>text</p>";

var start = str.indexOf("<img");
var end = str.indexOf("/>", (start));
var embed = str.substring(start, end) + "/>";
```

Comment: The problem here is angularjs doesn't have some way to get the tag that you want, so you have to handle the string. maybe exist another better way, but you can try with this. I hope it can serve you. Good Luck!!

Comment: Thanks Kenry!  This is what I needed. clap clap! ;)